# Xamarin IDE integration failed to deploy app

Tags: android, unit-testing, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

When i try to run unit-tests on a xamarin-android app, all tests fail because the IDE (VS 2015) couldn't find any devices or emulators to deploy the app to, although one is running.

If i run the app normally, it works.

VS Log Output:

```
Full log file: C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\log-2016-08-03_10-57-46-734.txt
Attempting IDE connection through pipe 0620e6c5f6094679bbb909f65a5f0702.
Deploying app through IDE.
Instructing the IDE to prepare the test app for execution. Session: Assembly=D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyTicketNativeApp\trunk\Cobeco.MyTicket.DroidApp.UITests\bin\Debug\Cobeco.MyTicket.DroidApp.UITests.DLL
Platform=Android
IDE integration failed to deploy app: There isn't any device or emulator available for running the application
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished
========== Run test finished: 11 run (0:00:02,6699974) ==========
```

Also, output of full log file:

```
    03-08-2016 10:57:46.749 +02:00 - 14 - Potential Android SDK location: (No path) - Not set. [ Source: ANDROID_HOME ]
03-08-2016 10:57:46.750 +02:00 - 15 - Potential Android SDK location: D:\Android - Valid SDK. [ Source: Registry ]
03-08-2016 10:57:46.750 +02:00 - 15 - Potential Android SDK location: D:\Android - Valid SDK. [ Source: Registry ]
03-08-2016 10:57:46.750 +02:00 - 15 - Using Android SDK: D:\Android
03-08-2016 10:57:46.750 +02:00 - 15 - Using JDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55 [ Source: Registry ]
03-08-2016 10:57:46.765 +02:00 - 30 - Attempting IDE connection for Android: D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyTicketNativeApp\trunk\Cobeco.MyTicket.DroidApp.UITests\bin\Debug\Cobeco.MyTicket.DroidApp.UITests.DLL.
03-08-2016 10:57:46.765 +02:00 - 31 - Attempting IDE connection through pipe 0620e6c5f6094679bbb909f65a5f0702.
03-08-2016 10:57:46.794 +02:00 - 59 - Deploying app through IDE.
03-08-2016 10:57:46.794 +02:00 - 60 - Instructing the IDE to prepare the test app for execution. Session: Assembly=D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyTicketNativeApp\trunk\Cobeco.MyTicket.DroidApp.UITests\bin\Debug\Cobeco.MyTicket.DroidApp.UITests.DLL
Platform=Android
03-08-2016 10:57:46.807 +02:00 - 73 - IDE integration failed to deploy app: There isn't any device or emulator available for running the application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. One has to set the ip to the device and the path to the apk file manually in the unit-test setup.

E.g.:

```
AndroidApp app = ConfigureApp
                .Android
                .DeviceIp("127.0.0.1") //Localhost because i use an emulator
                .ApkFile("<path-to-apk>")
                .StartApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, cannot comment yet) Have you tried reopening the emulator or connecting a physical device? And which emulator do you use? Are the target platforms(armeabi,x86,etc) adapted to your emulator device?

Comment: I tried reopening the emulator and restarting my computer multiple times. I haven't tried running it on a physical device but the project has to run on an emulator. Used emulators are Xamarin Android Player and the Google Emulators. Hyper-V doesn't work on my machine. Target platforms are adapted.

Comment: What emulator? And which supported architectures of your app?

Comment: Every architecture is marked as supported.

My main emulator is a Nexus 5 with Lollipop from the Xamarin Android Player